# How to Access package.json data inside the application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, package

i am setting a key using npm config set produrl 1234. Here how can i access produrl in side my application.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/config

clearly explains how to?

Comment: is it external plugin?

Comment: you have written in you question that you are using npm config.

Comment: here npm config indicates npmrc files

Comment: you will have to get it by using the command line in node, you can use shell or commander like modules

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read data from your package.json:

webpack.config.js:

```js
const Webpack = require('webpack');
const pkg = require('./package.json')

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new Webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        PROD_URL: JSON.stringify(pkg.produrl),
      },
    })
  ]
}
```

in your application:

```js
console.log(process.env.PROD_URL)
```